# System Interrupt - Start menu oftentimes does not work, task manager takes a few seconds to close

Tags: windows-10, start-menu, task-manager

MOST IMPORTANTLY: I have been seeing "System Interrupts" in my task manager since this happened with a constant 1.3%. I don't believe I have ever seen it when I sort processes by cpu usage before. I believe this to be a significant sign of what is wrong.

In 2015 I disabled windows update from the services and never updated for two years. I had no problems whatsoever. However, I installed malwarebyes (and lemme tell you, it found no malwares after two years of usage with no windows updates) maybe a week ago and I think it reverted my windows update settings. This morning I woke up to a new version of windows. I reverted to an earlier build. However, due to a folder C:/Windows10Upgrade, windows 10 upgrade assistant kept reinstalling itself and a process I never saw before called "windows telemetry [something something]" was taking up a lot of cpu so I googled it and found this thread: https://www.reddit.com/r/computertechs/comments/3kn4cf/mtrt_microsoft_telemetry_removal_tool_v10/

And since then, start menu has been malfunctioning(usually not working, only sometimes working), right clicking on the task bar has been malfunctioning (usually not working, only sometimes working), task manager has been taking unusually long time to close after I exit it (3-4 seconds)

However right when windows starts, everything is working fine. After maybe 30 seconds pass, then it starts to malfunction.

I tried rebuilding search index. Not much else comes to mind.

Comment: Can you run in a Powershell admin prompt:
`get-wmiobject -class win32_product > apps.txt` and link the output file apps.txt from the question? Pastebin link is fine for example.

Comment: @HelpingHand Thanks, but I reset the windows and all is fine. Itll cost me about 4-6 hours of my life, but at least I dont need to do further troubleshooting.

Comment: OK, I was specifically curious to know if you had HitmanPro installed.